# grab selected item from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to grab the value of the selected item from DropDownListFor and pass it as parameter.

my code looks like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, 
                      Model.Files, 
                      new 
                      { 
                       Name = "map", 
                       @class = "form-control", 
                       @onchange = "CallChangefunc('TheSelectedItemAsString');" 
                      })
```

I mean I'm foucoced on this: `@onchange = "CallChangefunc('TheSelectedItemAsString');"`

I need something like: `@onchange = "CallChangefunc('"+x.Value+"');"`

The `CallChangefunc` looks like:

```
<script>
function CallChangefunc(x) {
 //some code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this in `Jquery`:

```
$("#map").change(function () {
    var selectedValue = this.value; 
    alert("Selected Value: " + selectedValue);
});
```

or in javascript

```
@onchange = "CallChangefunc(this);
```

And get value of dropdownlist in `CallChangefunc` function

```
 function CallChangefunc(ddl) {
    var selectedValue = ddl.value;
    alert("Selected Value: " + selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: @Hossein `$("#map")` works in case of `id` i guess. Is it applicable in case of name too?

Comment: Its `$('#SelectedFileName').change(..`, not `$('#map').change(..`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your dropdown with this code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, 
                      Model.Files, 
                      new 
                      { 
                       @class = "form-control somevalue" 
                      })
```

and then  write `jquery` for this like

```
<script>
 var selectedDropDownValue;
 $(document).on('change', "select.somevalue", function () {
    selectedDropDownValue = $(this).val();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: @Flufy gd luck (y)

Comment: Buddy though i haven't downvoted it but i am sure lil research wd have got you answer for this question. Don't blindly post questions you will face downvote. Before posting do a bit of search. nd yes ofcourse if question is gd people will upvote

Comment: Seriously man ...r u for real. Upvote or to downvote is your wish. Noone is asking you to upvote ,it has to be your choice nd grow up a bit.